# Show that, $X_n \rightarrow 0, a.s$ $\Rightarrow$ $S_n/n \rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Problem: {X_n} is a sequence of random variables (not necessarily independent), $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_n$

show that,
$X_n \rightarrow 0, a.s$ $\Rightarrow$ $S_n/n \rightarrow 0$

It seems that since $X_n \rightarrow 0, a.s$ ,

$\Rightarrow $ $P(|X_n|>\epsilon, i.o)=0$

That is, $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{\infty}|X_n|>\epsilon)=0$

We want to show  $P(|S_n/n|>\epsilon, i.o)=0$

Since, $P(|S_n/n|>\epsilon, i.o)=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{\infty}|S_n/n|>\epsilon)=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{\infty}|\sum_{i=1}^nX_i/n|>\epsilon)$

My question, how to show the last equation converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$ or can anyone give some suggestion of this proof?

Comment: This statement is just true if all $X_i$ are almost sure finite.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion: show that for any real numbers $\{a_n\}$ if $a_n\to 0$, then $\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}\to 0$. Now $X_n\to 0$ a.s. so we have $S_n/n\to 0$ a.s. as well.